# How can I update geopandas to it's most recent version?

Tags: anaconda, geopandas

> I installed the geopandas package through anaconda using `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` , but for some reason the 0.6.3 version got installed.

> I need to use the `missing_kwds` function, but this function is only available in the latest versions of geopandas (currently it's 0.10.0).

> I tried updating it by checking `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas -h` and then using the `---update-all` but after hours of waiting I figured that wasn't right.
> Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: `missing_kwds` was released as a part of v.0.7.0.  You can install geopandas directly from git, but first uninstall the installed files of geopandas using pip or conda! Then, try using this command to install geopandas directly from the main branch: `pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda does not install latest available version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914559/conda-does-not-install-latest-available-version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the version number you want to install (example below).

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.10
```

If you're working in a conda env (which I would highly advise, along with running the 2 conda config steps on the [conda-forge home page](https://conda-forge.org/) on your machine to add the conda-forge channel and prioritize installing packages from the conda-forge channel), make sure you've already activated your env before running that install command.