# How to update geopandas?

Tags: pip, geopandas

Currently I got geopandas 0.9.0 from `pip install geopandas`,

I try to follow this instruction
[How can I update geopandas to it's most recent version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69574108/how-can-i-update-geopandas-to-its-most-recent-version) ,
(conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.10 )

but `bash: conda: command not found ...`

Is there any solution to insatall geopandas 0.10.0 or later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have install geopandas using `pip`, you should also update it using pip.

```sh
pip install geopandas -U
```

The `-U` or `--upgrade` flag ensures you get the latest version no matter the one installed.

Comment: Seconding this recommendation - and to add/rephrase slightly, do not use `conda` to update something that was originally installed using `pip`